# Set up SMTP server to add global signature to all emails from Google Apps for Business

Tags: g-suite, smtp

We are using Google Apps for Business for our mail server, but require a global signature (simple HTML) to be appended to every message sent. This is not a feature of Google Apps, although it is possible to use an Outbound mail gateway.

I was wondering if it would be applicable to set up a simple SMTP server to append the signature, or if that would be overkill. If so, could someone write a short guide to the best email server to use and how to do this simple task, as we have never set up our own email server (although have set up plenty of web servers before).

We have a Debian Squeeze server with an external IP address that we would like to use.

Comment: You won't do that. First Google Apps and Googlemail support adding (default) signatures. I see it in my accounts. Second all mails have to be send to your server and then back to Google to be delivered to the recipient. Is it that what you really want?

Comment: @mailq I see no other way of providing a global signature for *all* users - rather than local signature for *each* user.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give a try to Postini, in particular to feature called Compliance Footer. More info here: http://www.postini.com/webdocs/admin_ee_cu/ob_foot.html It depends on the complexity of your signature, though.

Cheers